# Build a dataframe based on new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 9 columns (my real data is very big). I want to consider 4 by 4 columns and build a
new dataframe with 2 columns which shows the summation of those 4 columns. Here is a simple example:
I want to have the id column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df['a'] = [10, 0, 1, 3]
df['b'] = [-10, 0, 2, 2]
df['c'] = [0, 1, 3, 3]
df['d'] = [0, 0, 4, 4]
df['e'] = [10, 0, 1, 3]
df['f'] = [10, 0, 2, 2]
df['g'] = [0, -1, 0, 0]
df['h'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the underlying numpy array for an easy way to reshape:

```
a = df.drop(columns='id').to_numpy()
N = 4 # number of columns to group
df2 = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape((len(df), -1, N)).sum(2),
                   columns=[f'value{x+1}' for x in range(a.shape[1]//N)],
                   index=df['id']).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   id  value1  value2
0   1       0      20
1   2       1      -1
2   3      10       3
3   4      12       5
```

Comment: Thanks. I have thousand columns. Do you know how can set the name of column. Here we only have two column.

Comment: you can use a list comprehention: `[f'value{x+1}' for x in range(1000//4)]` (for 1000 initial columns) or `[f'value{x+1}' for x in range(len(df.columns[1:])//4)]`

Comment: Also note that here I specified to have 2 columns in the end: `a.reshape((-1, 2, len(df)))` in your case you should use `a.reshape((4, -1, len(df)))`

Comment: Here I have one problem yet. So, in the case if I have 5000 rows, with 1000 columns. How I should reshape the df?

Comment: @Whitecow I had done a mistake in the order to reshape, check the update, I took the opportunity to make the code generic ;)

Comment: Yes. It gives me an error. can noy reshape array of size 48440000 to (4,1,5000).